# Extract RPM to directory other than current directory

Tags: bash, shell, extract, rpm, cpio

I am needing to run:

```
rpm2cpio mypackage.rpm | cpio -idmv
```

However, I need the output to be in a different directory. Is there a more elegant solution than doing

```
mv <output> <to/other/directory>
```

after performing the extraction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `cpio` is just reading from standard input, you can change to another directory before running it:

```
rpm2cpio mypackage.rpm | (cd /to/other/directory; cpio -idmv)
```

This is a general solution that will work with a variety of tools.  The `cpio` command has a `--directory` (`-D`) option that will accomplish the same thing:

```
rpm2cpio mypackage.rpm | cpio -D /to/other/directory -idmv
```

Answer (score 2):

Or even easier:

`rpmdev-extract -C DIR mypackage.rpm`

Comment: Verily, mine quest hath at long last reached its conclusion! Methinks 'tis time to raise a tankard of ale and toast to mine triumph! 